# Curiously Recurring Template Pattern -- Inheritance and friends

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, namespaces, crtp

### Intro

I am trying to use the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern to make things storable in hdf5 groups.
But I have two problems:

1. How to make the member implementation private?
2. How to use the CRTP with namespaces?

### What I want

(The code follows) `hdf5::Group` represents an hdf5 group, and can store datasets.`hdf5::Storable` is a CRTP template class. The function `hdf5::store` should take a group and a storable object and call the object's implementation. All these should be inside the namespace `hdf5` to keep things clean.

`A` implements a storable. It lives outside the `hdf5` namespace (e.g. global, or another namespace). The implementation method `A::store` should be private, to make sure that everyone uses `hdf5::store` instead.

### What I have

The parts in question have comments pointing out the problems.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace hdf5 {

/// A group can contain other groups, and datasets.
class Group {
public:
    /// Create a group under a parent group.
    Group(Group* parent, const std::string &name)
        : parent_(parent), name_(name)
    {
        std::cout << "Creating group \"" << name << "\"";
        if (parent != nullptr)
            std::cout << " under \"" << parent->name_ << "\"";
        std::cout  << "." << std::endl;
    };

    /// Create a root group.
    Group() : Group(nullptr, "root") { }

    /// Create a dataset inside.
    void create_dataset(const std::string &name)
    {
        std::cout << "Creating dataset \"" << name << "\""
            << " under \"" << name_ << "\"." << std::endl;
    }

private:
    Group *parent_;
    std::string name_;
};

/** Abstraction of a storable class.
 *
 * Curiously recurring template pattern.
 * Makes it possible to write
 *
 *     store(grp, obj);
 *
 */
template<class Derived>
class Storable {
    friend void hdf5::store(hdf5::Group &grp, const Derived &obj) {
        obj.store(grp);
    }
};

}  // namespace hdft


/// Some data class that should be storable.
class A : private hdf5::Storable<A> {
public:
    A(const std::string &name) : name_(name) { }

/*
 * Why can't I make it private? `store` should be friend.
 *
 *     test.cc: In instantiation of ‘void hdf5::store(hdf5::Group&, const A&)’:
 *     test.cc:104:19:   required from here
 *     test.cc:72:10: error: ‘void A::store(hdf5::Group&) const’ is private
 *          void store(hdf5::Group &grp) const {
 *               ^
 *     test.cc:45:9: error: within this context
 *              obj.store(grp);
 *              ^
 */
// private:
public:
    /// Implementation of the storage
    void store(hdf5::Group &grp) const {
        grp.create_dataset(name_);
    }

private:
    std::string name_;
};


/// Demonstration.
int main(void) {
    hdf5::Group root,
          grpa(&root, std::string("group_a")),
          grpb(&root, std::string("group_b"));
    A a1(std::string("A1")), a2(std::string("A2"));

    /*
     * This is what I want, but it doesn't compile:
     *
     *     test.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
     *     test.cc:96:5: error: ‘store’ is not a member of ‘hdf5’
     *          hdf5::store(root, a1);
     *          ^
     */
    // hdf5::store(root, a1);
    // hdf5::store(root, a2);
    // hdf5::store(grpa, a1);
    // hdf5::store(grpb, a2);

    /*
     * This OTOH compiles and runs.
     */
    store(root, a1);
    store(root, a2);
    store(grpa, a1);
    store(grpb, a2);
}
```

### The Expected Output

```
Creating group "root".
Creating group "group_a" under "root".
Creating group "group_b" under "root".
Creating dataset "A1" under "root".
Creating dataset "A2" under "root".
Creating dataset "A1" under "group_a".
Creating dataset "A2" under "group_b".
```

Comment: friendship is not transitive.

Comment: Well, it's true that friendship isn't transitive, but in this case it's an issue of friendship not being passed down to your descendent classes. Friendship works on a class-by-class basis, as far as I understand it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Why should `A` and `Group` be related? `A` could be anythin, e.g. a matrix class, or a data-table, or a complex object...

`hdf5::store` is actually defined at the friend declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following changes seem to work: https://ideone.com/CRuLkb

```
namespace hdf5 {

// Previous stuff

template <class Derived> void store(hdf5::Group &grp, const Derived&obj);

template<class Derived>
class Storable {
    static void store(hdf5::Group &grp, const Derived&obj)
    {
        obj.store(grp);
    }

    friend void hdf5::store<>(hdf5::Group &grp, const Derived&obj);
};

template <class Derived>
void store(hdf5::Group &grp, const Derived&obj) {
    Storable<Derived>::store(grp, obj);
}


}  // namespace hdf5


/// Some data class that should be storable.
class A : private hdf5::Storable<A> {
    friend class hdf5::Storable<A>;
private:
    /// Implementation of the storage
    void store(hdf5::Group &grp) const {
        grp.create_dataset(name_);
    }
private:
    std::string name_;
};
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. Do you know if there is a way to write this, so that you do not need a friend declaration in `A`? Other than making `A::store` public that is. As I understand your solution, and what I read elsewhere, friends are not inherited. The only way they can be *effectively inherited* is through virtual methods, correct?

Comment: If you create `virtual hdf5::Storable<A>::store(hdf5::Group &grp) const`, `A::Store` may be call via `hdf5::Storable<A>` as follow `static_cast<const hdf5::Storable<A>&>(obj).store(grp);`, and you may remove a `friend`.

Comment: [works indeed](https://ideone.com/nHbxnm). However, it requires public inhertiance, and comes at the cost of a vtable. But compared to the actual storing, the vtable is probably negligible...